# Pass a String from application to a web search in Swift

Tags: swift, string, webview, safari

For my final year project in college I'm making an application that will the user to source and purchase whatever they take a picture of. The use case I've presented is that if a user takes a photograph of a pair of shoes, the application will return a link to where they can buy these/similar shoes.

So far I have the app identifying what is in the image, displaying a string that's populated by the API. This string could be "brown shoes" / "computer desk", in theory it could be anything.

What I'd like to do is to get the app to put this string variable into a web search, and return links to where a user could buy it. I have not tried any way to implement this as I'm not sure how to.

Is there a way I could do this? Thanks

Comment: This one of those questions that people down vote because they don't know the answer or have I missed something?

Comment: No one down votes because they don't know the answer. Hover your mouse over the down vote array. The tooltip text shows the reasons that people might down vote a question. Your question is unclear. It's vague and broad. What exactly do you need help with? What have you tried? Update your question with relevant code clearly showing what you need help with. Please put all relevant details in your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a Google search and include the search string in it, so basically:

1. Open Safari
2. Add the URL including the search string
3. A new Google search will be done with the search string

Note that you need to encode the search string, because it can contain
 spaces like in "Brown shoes".

```
let word = "Brown shoes"
if let encoded = word.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed), let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/#q=\(encoded)") {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

This will return the following URL: [https://www.google.com/#q=Brown%20shoes](http://url%09URL), which will be opened in Safari.